# How to use doWaitForCondition?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

How do I use doWaitForCondition in a Selenium user extension? 
this.doWaitForCondition() returns a function, but when I run it it returns immediately.

Comment: take a look at this, this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195139/what-are-the-inner-workings-of-the-selenium-waitfor-mechanism

Comment: Looks promising. I'll test it and check if it works well. The idea is great, but the implementation details are a bit sketchy; is myAppIsBusy() implemented in the selenium extension to check whether the condition is finished?

Comment: No luck so far. I posted a few comments on that question.